# RTCPeerConnection connectionState never moves from "new" to "checking"/"connected"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

I have taken over a WebRTC project from someone and though I'm starting to wrap my head around the concepts, I continue to be stumped by a specific problem: getting the WebRTC connection to move from `new` to `checking`/`completed`, etc...

Here is the extent of the output from `chrome://webrtc-internals`:

[image]

Our code calls `connect()`:

```
connect(mediaStream, interviewUid, applicantUid) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.connectRtcPeerConnection()
        .then(() => {
          this.connectionState = Socket.CONNECTION_STATES.connected;
          this.rtcPeer.addStream(mediaStream);
          return this.rtcPeer.createOffer({ offerToReceiveAudio: 1, offerToReceiveVideo: 1 });
        }).then((offer) => {
          console.log('offer created', offer);
          return this.rtcPeer.setLocalDescription(offer);
        }).then(() => {
          const message = {
            id: SENDABLE_MESSAGES.connect,
            sdpOffer: this.rtcPeer.localDescription,
            interviewUid,
            applicantUid,
          };
          this.sendMessageToServer(message);
          resolve();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
          reject();
        });
    });
  }
```

which in turns calls `connectRtcPeerConnection()`:

connectRtcPeerConnection(

```
) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (this.rtcPeer) {
        resolve();
      }
      console.log('started connecting');

      const rtcPeerOptions = {
        iceServers: [TRUNCATED],
      };

      console.log('rtcPeerOptions', rtcPeerOptions);
      this.rtcPeer = new RTCPeerConnection(rtcPeerOptions);
      console.log('rtcPeer object: ', this.rtcPeer);
      this.rtcPeer.onerror = reject;
      this.rtcPeer.onicecandidate = (candidate) => { this.handleIceCandidateEvent(candidate); };
      this.rtcPeer.oniceconnectionstatechange = () => {
        this.handleIceConnectionStateChangeEvent();
      };
      this.rtcPeer.onaddstream = () => { console.log('handleAddStreamEvent'); };
      this.rtcPeer.onremovestream = () => { console.log('handleRemoveStreamEvent'); };
      this.rtcPeer.onicegatheringstatechange = () => { console.log('handleIceGatheringStateChangeEvent'); };
      this.rtcPeer.onsignalingstatechange = () => { console.log('handleSignalingStateChangeEvent'); };
      this.rtcPeer.onnegotiationneeded = () => { console.log('handleNegotiationNeededEvent'); };
      resolve();
    });
  }
```

This chunk of code never gets executed:

```
this.rtcPeer.oniceconnectionstatechange = () => {
  this.handleIceConnectionStateChangeEvent();
};
```

I've followed every conditional and code path and don't currently see what the issue might be. Has anyone encountered this and is able to shed some light on potential things to look at/consider?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When I was implementing Kurento library for iOS, tried something like this:

> Generated SDPOffer
>
> Set LocalDescription at our end
>
> WebRTC started generating IceCandidate
>
> Sent Ice Candidate through WebSocket
>
> At this point, other party sent SDPAnswer.
>
> Processed SDPAnswer at our end.
>
> Set RemoteDescription at our end.
>
> Server started sending IceCandidate gathered at their end.
>
> Added these IceCandidate in array at our end.
>
> *Here received change in connection state to "Checking"*
>
> Received RemoteStream at this point.
>
> *Here received change in connection state to "Connected"*

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I think I've narrowed the issue down to our coturn server. I'm seeing some 'allocation timeout' error lines. Your workflow is useful though! Once I figure out the coturn stuff, if this still isn't working, I'll use this as a guide

Answer (score 0):

well, you never call setRemoteDescription or add a remote ice candidate via addIceCandidate. Without that there is no-one to talk to

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn't include those code snippets but we have a `onWebsocketMessage` function that, based on the message received, will dispatch other function calls. `setRemoteDescription` and `addIceCandidate` are two of the functions that do get called during execution

Comment: the webrtc-internals screenshot doesn't show them so you might want to check this gets routed to the correct peerconnection